# 2D numerical integration in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I know how to perform a double integral in python

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

integrate.dblquad(x*y, 0, 1, lambda x: -np.sqrt(1-x**2), lambda x: np.sqrt(1-x**2))
```

where `x` and `y` are, say, `(200,)` numpy arrays.

However, what if the integrand (`x*y`) above is a 2D array rather than a function? In my case, I have an array `Z` which has a value at every coordinate (x,y), i.e. it has shape `(200,200)`. However, I do not know in advance the continuous function(s) that it would correspond to.

How would I perform this integral? Thanks.

Comment: Integration is over a continuous domain by definition; over a discrete set of values it's just a summation. So can't you just sum up all the values in the array multiplied by the area of each grid cell?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your comment. You are absolutely right. I am stupid and also exhausted from work, which is a dangerous mix. Thanks again.

Comment: There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20668689/8069403), for which nested 1D integration using Simpson's method is proposed (same idea as the direct sum, but accuracy is improved by assuming that the function is locally quadratic). However, the integration domain is still rectangular...

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to integrate a function over the unit disk? You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) to do that. It does support vector-valued integrands, too:

```py
import numpy
import quadpy

scheme = quadpy.disk.lether(6)  # there are many other schemes available
# scheme.show()
val = scheme.integrate(
    lambda x: [numpy.exp(x[0] + x[1]), numpy.cos(x[0])],
    [0.0, 0.0],  # disk center
    1.0  # disk radius
)
print(val)
```

```
[3.99523707 2.76491937]
```

Comment: Following what was pointed out in the comments, I just did a double summation and it worked fine. However, quadpy seems interesting. Is there anywhere I can find an explanation on the syntax used? I am unsure what, for example, `[0.0, 0.0], 1.0` or `x[0]` and `x[1]` stand for in the above code. Thanks

Comment: center, radius of the disk. `x[0]` and `x[1]` are simply the coordinates (x and y if you want).

Comment: What if the function I want to integrate is not actually a function, but an array of values corresponding to various points within the domain of integration? Thanks.

Comment: If the points where the function is prescribed are fixed, you're outside of the domain of classical numerical integration. There not too much you can do there. One sensible thing would be to construct the Voronoi tesselation of your domain with the points inside and sum them up weighted with the Voronoi volumes.